# `JSON.stringify` omits custom keys in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, stringification

I am storing my array as a mixture of array an array and an object. For example assume this one:

```
let arrObj = [];
arrObj["x"] = 12;
arrObj.push(12);
arrObj["y"] = 15;
arrObj.push(15);

// result: arrObj = [12, 15, x: 12, y: 15]
```

so that, I can access the value `12` even using `arrObj[0]` and `arrObj["x"]`. And this way, I can do a repeat for on it.

But when I stringify it, the keys `x` and `y` get lost:

```
JSON.stringify(arrObj)
// result: "[12,15]"
```

How should I maintain those keys and their values?

Comment: This is not a valid JSON string: `"[ 12, 15, 'x': 12, 'y': 15 ]"`. Even if you output it, you won't be able to parse it as JSON. So it's not clear how this could work without some sort of transformation.

Comment: That's enough for me to make this structure valid for myself. I mean, at the other end I myself am catching the value, so that I can manipulate that end too.

Comment: `[...arrObj.values()] // [12, 15] ` is the actual result. Dont confuse with x and y. They are just properties of `arrObj` array

Comment: @AswinKumar I want `x` and `y` for direct access in future.

Comment: @ConductedClever Then Pranav C Balan's updated answer using object is abt for your case

Comment: Of course @AswinKumar. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While stringifying convert it to an object using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and later parse and use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to generate the array.

The array keeps the property since Array is also an object in Javascript.

```js
let arrObj = [];
arrObj["x"] = 12;
arrObj.push(12);
arrObj["y"] = 15;
arrObj.push(15);

let json = JSON.stringify({ ...arrObj });

console.log(json);

let parsed = Object.entries(JSON.parse(json)).reduce((arr, [key, value]) => (arr[key] = value, arr), []);

console.log(parsed);
```

**FYI :** But it always better to use an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) or [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for key-value pair data, not better that's the right way in my opinion.

---

***UPDATE 1:*** Or you can use a main object which keeps all additional property and within it create a property which keeps the array as well.

```js
let arrObj = {
  arr: []
};
arrObj["x"] = 12;
arrObj.arr.push(12);
arrObj["y"] = 15;
arrObj.arr.push(15);

let json = JSON.stringify(arrObj);

console.log(json);

let parsed = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(parsed);
```

---

***UPDATE 2:*** The second approach cause issue if you are trying to set property named `arr`(in my case) so keep object  values in separate property.

```js
let arrObj = {
  arr: [],
  obj: {}
};
arrObj.obj["x"] = 12;
arrObj.arr.push(12);
arrObj.obj["y"] = 15;
arrObj.arr.push(15);

let json = JSON.stringify(arrObj);

console.log(json);

let parsed = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(parsed);
```

Comment: Thanks. Map is good in accepting key-value pair and repeating but not serializable.

Comment: The second solution also is good but it will break my extension methos: `Array.prototype.pushNamed = function (key, value) {
  this[key] = value;
  this.push(value);
  return this;
}`

Comment: @ConductedClever :  rewrite it like `Object.prototype.pushNamed = function (key, value) { this[key] = value; this.arr.push(value); return this; }`

Comment: @ConductedClever ;)

Comment: @ConductedClever :  for the new approach it would be like `Object.prototype.pushNamed = function (key, value) { this.obj[key] = value; this.arr.push(value); return this; }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190963/discussion-between-pranav-c-balan-and-conductedclever).

Answer (score 0):

Arrays should contain numeric-indexed values only. If you want *keys* in addition to values, use an object:

```js
const obj = {};
obj.x = 12;
obj[0] = 12;
obj.y = 15;
obj[1] = 15;

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));

for (let i = 0; i in obj; i++) {
  console.log(obj[i]);
}
```

You could also consider using an object that contains both an array and your custom key-value pairs, eg:

```js
const arr = [];
const obj = { arr };
obj.x = 12;
obj.y = 15;
arr.push(12);
arr.push(15);

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Comment: I want it to be an array to let foreach on it. This is not the answer of mine.

Comment: If you want to preserve the arbitrary keys over stringification, use an object instead, and then transform it into an array when you need to use `forEach`.

Comment: And the transformation will force additional costs every time I call it. I think it is better to have it as array from the beginning. Although unless it be impossible.

Comment: Stringified arrays *cannot* have arbitrary key-value pairs. If you need arbitrary key-value pairs to be saved over serialization, you have to use an object, not an array.

Comment: now the answer got better. And what about manipulating `JSON.stringify` itself to let arbitrary key-value pairs?

Comment: If you do that, the result will not be valid JSON, and won't be parseable by anything but a custom parser you build, which would be difficult and a bad idea.

Comment: But the idea you call it bad is my desired way and I am looking for it.

Comment: And if it's a custom parser, then by definition, you're not dealing with JSON, since JSON parses don't work. Also, wanting to foreach the array is a bad justification for breaking standards.

Comment: @ConductedClever I belueve yours is an XY problem - do you want to have a custom serialisation format *or* simply have a foreach-able object?

Comment: I'm not going to recommend/show the custom parsing technique that results in invalid JSON - like @VLAZ said, it's a bad idea, simply using an object instead is far easier.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fancy 1 liner solution:

```js
let arrObj = [];
    arrObj["x"] = 12;
    arrObj.push(12);
    arrObj["y"] = 15;
    arrObj.push(15);

var string = JSON.stringify(Object.keys(arrObj).reduce((acc, cur) => ((acc[cur] = arrObj[cur]), acc), {}));

console.log(string);
```

P.S: I thought it's worthy to mention that you might encounter an unexpected behaviour because in JS, there is no guarantee that object properties are ordered (as you wanted to).
[Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: Although the order is not important for me but the stringified object is not as desired. Thanks.